# Read Laptop Battery Status in Float/Double

Tags: c++, winapi, power-management

I have a program that reads battery status in Windows that looks like this (simplified code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS spsPwr;
    if( GetSystemPowerStatus(&spsPwr) ) {
        cout << "\nAC Status : " << static_cast<double>(spsPwr.ACLineStatus)
             << "\nBattery Status : " << static_cast<double>(spsPwr.BatteryFlag)
             << "\nBattery Life % : " << static_cast<double>(spsPwr.BatteryLifePercent)
             << endl;
        return 0;
    } else return 1;
}
```

`spsPwr.BatteryLifePercent` holds remaining battery charge in percent and is of type `BYTE`, which means it can only show reading in round numbers (i.e. `int`). I notice that an application called [BatteryBar](http://images.snapfiles.com/screenfiles/batterybar.jpg) can show battery percentage in floating point value.

BatteryBar is a .NET application. How can I get battery percentage reading in float/double using pure C/C++ with Windows API? (Solution that can be compiled with MinGW is preferable)

Comment: Do you mean you want more precision? Or do you mean you want BatteryLife out of 1?

Comment: Please upload that image properly using Stack Overflow's post tools; the image you posted a link to cannot be hotlinked.

Comment: @Tomalak: I want to get a reading that shows decimal value (e.g. 22.5, 87.5). And I'm not allowed to post an image due to my rep.

Comment: Then at least post an URL that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this information using the WMI . try using the `BatteryFullChargedCapacity` and `BatteryStatus` classes both are part of the `root\WMI` namespace.

To get the remaining battery charge in percent just must use the  `RemainingCapacity` (BatteryStatus) and `FullChargedCapacity` (BatteryFullChargedCapacity)  properties.

The remaining battery charge in percent is

(RemainingCapacity * 100) / FullChargedCapacity

for example if the FullChargedCapacity property report a `5266` value and the  RemainingCapacity reports a  `5039`, the reuslt will be `95,68932776 %`

If you don't know how access the WMI from C++ read these articles

- [`WMI C++ Application Examples`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Making WMI Queries In C++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/UsingWMI.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you said, the Windows API [provides only an integral percentage value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms704147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And, as you implied, .NET [provides a floating-point one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.powerstatus.batterylifepercent.aspx).

That means that, to use the floating-point one, you have to use .NET. That said, the .NET value is between `0.0` and `1.0`, and it's not clear from the documentation whether you actually gain more precision.

Answer (score 0):

The tool states that it does "[Statistical Time Prediction](http://osirisdevelopment.com/BatteryBar/)" so I doubt it uses the direct value of [`SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Personally, I hardly can imagine what a floating-point precision would be good for, but anyway you could use [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) to see how they are doing it, or maybe you also could ask them how they do.

Answer (score -1):

The .NET version doesn't actually provide you any more precision. It simply divides the `BatterLifePercent` byte value by 100.0 and returns the result. Here are the contents of the getter in .NET.

```
public float BatteryLifePercent
{
    get
    {
        this.UpdateSystemPowerStatus();
        float num = ((float) this.systemPowerStatus.BatteryLifePercent) / 100f;
        if (num <= 1f)
        {
            return num;
        }
        return 1f;
    }
}
```

`UpdateSystemPowerStatus()` calls WINAPI's `GetSystemPowerStatus()`, which in turn updates `systemPowerStatus`.